# Visualisation of 10-12 star-based-items in a review site

Tags: info-visualisation, data, quantitative-analysis, expert-review

I need to create a page with 10 or 12 items. Each item is a criteria for review  that can be voted by the user between 1 and 4 stars. But, the problem is that it is a really strange visualisation to put all these items in a column, one below the other. How can I improve the visualisation of these metrics star-based items?

Comment: Can't picture it, got a sketch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand, you need to show n number of rate-able criteria without making them boring.

You could use 3*n(4 if 12) grid or scroll-able groups. Let me show...

[image]